# Facebook Publish_action is not working for posting

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Hi I am trying to post on facebook from my iOS app, before it worked fine. Now I use the latest SDK and following code.

-(void)Authentication{

```
   if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

        [self promptUserWithAccountNameForUploadPhoto];

     } else {

        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"publish_actions",
                            nil];  // Tried publish_stream too

      [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                  FBSessionState status,
                                                  NSError *error) {
                                  // if login fails for any reason, we alert
                                  if (error) {

                                      // show error to user.


                                  } else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status)) {



                                      [self promptUserWithAccountNameForUploadPhoto];


                                   }
                               }];


               }

     }
```

But when it launches Facebook app and login is done, it doen't notify the user about "Post on your behalf", it notifies my app requires your profile details instead.

And when I try to Post like below

```
  -(void)promptUserWithAccountNameForUploadPhoto {

        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
     if (!error) {


         NSString * msgStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I have added a new Trip to %@",place];
         NSString *imgStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@assets/upload/flags/%@-213x142.png",appDelegate.ServerURL,country];



         NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        @"Sharing Tutorial", @"name",
                                        @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
                                        @"Allow your users to share stories on Facebook from your app using the iOS SDK.", @"description",
                                               @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/", @"link",
                                        @"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png", @"picture",
                        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                   if (!error) {
                                       // Link posted successfully to Facebook
                                       NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
                                   } else {

                                       NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
                                   }
                               }];

                   }

               }];

           }
```

An error comes as - 
**message = "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action";**

Answer (score 0):

from `error code` it looks like you don't have `permission for share`

see `facebook error code`[here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/error-reference/)

for get `sharing permission` refer [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/)

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown when you are using `publish_actions` permission without review. For testing purpose you can always make a test user in Roles column of MyApp in developers.facebook.com and then use it..